# Copying text to clipboard Error CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat'

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

maybe I'm asking really stupid question but for an hour and half I have tried to solve it myself now I gave up. Here is code that keep giving me an error

FULL:

```
Clipboard.SetText("string[,] TAB1 = new string[2, 2];\r\nfor (int STEV1 = 0; STEV1 < TAB1.GetLength(0); STEV1++)\r\n{\r\nfor (int STEV2 = 0; STEV2 < TAB1.GetLength(1); STEV2++)\r\n{\r\nTAB1[STEV1, STEV2] = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());\r\nConsole.Clear();\r\n}\r\n}\r\nConsole.Clear();\r\nMETODA1(TAB1);\r\nConsole.ReadLine();\r\n}\r\nprivate static void METODA1(string[,] TAB1)\r\n{\r\nfor (int STEV3 = 0; STEV3 < TAB1.GetLength(0); STEV3++)\r\n{\r\nfor (int STEV4 = 0; STEV4 < TAB1.GetLength(1); STEV4++)\r\n{\r\nConsole.Write(TAB1[STEV3, STEV4] + " ");\r\n}\r\nConsole.WriteLine();\r\n}");
```

UNDERLINED:

Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat'

```
");\r\n}\r\nConsole.WriteLine();\r\n}"
```

Anyone knows how to solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clipboard.SetText("string[,] TAB1 = new string[2, 2];\r\nfor (int STEV1 = 0; STEV1 < TAB1.GetLength(0); STEV1++)\r\n{\r\nfor (int STEV2 = 0; STEV2 < TAB1.GetLength(1); STEV2++)\r\n{\r\nTAB1[STEV1, STEV2] = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());\r\nConsole.Clear();\r\n}\r\n}\r\nConsole.Clear();\r\nMETODA1(TAB1);\r\nConsole.ReadLine();\r\n}\r\nprivate static void METODA1(string[,] TAB1)\r\n{\r\nfor (int STEV3 = 0; STEV3 < TAB1.GetLength(0); STEV3++)\r\n{\r\nfor (int STEV4 = 0; STEV4 < TAB1.GetLength(1); STEV4++)\r\n{\r\nConsole.Write(TAB1[STEV3, STEV4] + \" \");\r\n}\r\nConsole.WriteLine();\r\n}");
```

Double quotes inside the string aren't escaped. Try using the above.

Comment: Oh god, now I feel so stupid. I should have known that. Thanks!